# How to make single SQL query without using UNION for more than 2 SQL statements?

Tags: sql, oracle

```
SELECT 'INITIALIZE' AS PROCESS_DESC,
  floor((MAX(EXEC_DATE)-MIN(EXEC_DATE))*24)
  || ' HOURS '
  || mod(floor((MAX(EXEC_DATE)-MIN(EXEC_DATE))*24*60),60)
  || ' MINUTES '
  || mod(floor((MAX(EXEC_DATE)-MIN(EXEC_DATE))*24*60*60),60)
  || ' SECS ' time_difference
FROM spool_table
WHERE process_desc                         ='INITIALIZE'
AND to_date(EXEC_DATE, 'DD-MON-YYYY')      =
  (SELECT to_date(EXEC_DATE, 'DD-MON-YYYY')=
  FROM spool_table
  WHERE process_desc='INITIALIZE'
  )
UNION ALL
SELECT 'PRELIM' AS PROCESS_DESC,
  floor((MAX(EXEC_DATE)-MIN(EXEC_DATE))*24)
  || ' HOURS '
  || mod(floor((MAX(EXEC_DATE)-MIN(EXEC_DATE))*24*60),60)
  || ' MINUTES '
  || mod(floor((MAX(EXEC_DATE)-MIN(EXEC_DATE))*24*60*60),60)
  || ' SECS ' time_difference
FROM spool_table
WHERE process_desc                   ='PRELIM'
AND to_date(EXEC_DATE, 'DD-MON-YYYY')=
  (SELECT to_date(MAX(EXEC_DATE), 'DD-MON-YYYY')
  FROM spool_table
  WHERE process_desc='PRELIM'
  )
```

Comment: `to_date(MAX(EXEC_DATE), 'DD-MON-YYYY')` in the second half of the `UNION` ... is this a mistake?

Comment: SELECT 'PRELIM' AS PROCESS_DESC
...
WHERE process_desc                   ='PRELIM'

are you serious?

Comment: can you modify the query to make it simple and result oriented?

Comment: HOW DO WE ADD WHERE CONDITION  NOT IN PROCESS_DESC COLUMN --SELECT 'MEASURE' AS PROCESS_DESC,
  floor((MAX(EXEC_DATE)-MIN(EXEC_DATE))*24)
  || ' HOURS '
  || mod(floor((MAX(EXEC_DATE)-MIN(EXEC_DATE))*24*60),60)
  || ' MINUTES '
  || mod(floor((MAX(EXEC_DATE)-MIN(EXEC_DATE))*24*60*60),60)
  || ' SECS ' time_difference
FROM spool_table
WHERE process_desc  NOT IN ('INITIALIZE','PRELIM')
AND to_date(EXEC_DATE, 'DD-MON-YYYY')=
  (SELECT to_date(MAX(EXEC_DATE), 'DD-MON-YYYY')
  FROM spool_table
  WHERE process_desc NOT IN ('INITIALIZE','PRELIM');

Comment: This query makes absolutely no sense. Please explain what business logic you need to implement; it will help if you provide some sample data from SPOOL_TABLE and desired output

Comment: while running engine for measure execution . all the logs will be saved in spool_table. From that spool table, i want to calculate the time taken by each process  with process_desc like (initialize, prelim, not in initialize and prelim) description with actual time calculation in the separate rows ? In above question i do union all for selecting the time_difference for each process but i want a single query without using union all for all same repetitive SQL statements. Any help will be appreciated ?

Comment: i need some serious help to get the solutions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use FIRST (or LAST) in this case to find the min datetime on the latest date:

```
with cte (process_desc, max_exec_date, min_exec_date) as (
    select 
        process_desc,
        max(exec_date) max_exec_date,
        min(exec_date) keep (dense_rank last order by trunc(exec_date) nulls first) min_exec_date
    from spool_table s
    where process_desc in ('PRELIM', 'INITIALIZE') -- include or exclude what process you want here
    group by process_desc
)
select
    process_desc,
    floor((max_exec_date-min_exec_date)*24) || ' HOURS ' ||
    mod(floor((max_exec_date-min_exec_date)*24*60),60)  || ' MINUTES ' ||
    mod(floor((max_exec_date-min_exec_date)*24*60*60),60) 
    || ' SECS ' time_difference
from cte;
```

the CTE is there to clarify the query. You can put it as a subquery if you want or even without a subquery like this:

```
select
    process_desc,
    floor((max(exec_date)-min(exec_date) keep (dense_rank last order by trunc(exec_date) nulls first))*24) || ' HOURS ' ||
    mod(floor((max(exec_date)-min(exec_date) keep (dense_rank last order by trunc(exec_date) nulls first))*24*60),60)   || ' MINUTES ' ||
    mod(floor((max(exec_date)-min(exec_date) keep (dense_rank last order by trunc(exec_date) nulls first))*24*60*60),60) 
    || ' SECS ' time_difference
from spool_table s
where process_desc in ('PRELIM', 'INITIALIZE')
group by process_desc;
```

A bit Naive way is using correlated subquery:

```
select process_desc,
  floor((max(exec_date)-min(exec_date))*24)
  || ' HOURS '
  || mod(floor((max(exec_date)-min(exec_date))*24*60),60)
  || ' MINUTES '
  || mod(floor((max(exec_date)-min(exec_date))*24*60*60),60)
  || ' SECS ' time_difference
from spool_table s
where process_desc in ('PRELIM', 'INITIALIZE')
and trunc(exec_date) = (
    select trunc(max(exec_date))
    from spool_table t
    where t.process_desc = s.process_desc
)
group by process_desc;
```

Comment: how do we add where process_desc not in ('initialize', 'prelim') in the above sql query?

Comment: @nawaraj - I just added `process_desc in ('PRELIM', 'INITIALIZE')`. You can replace it there. Why do you now want to add `process_desc not in ('PRELIM', 'INITIALIZE')`?? What exactly is your goal?

Comment: i have to select process_desc not in ('INITILIZE','PRELIM') too along with above query in same single sql statement that returns the values in distinct process_desc rows with time difference. Is that possible? Your help will be appreciated GurV?

Comment: then don't put the where clause at all. You'll get all the processes in separate rows

Comment: SELECT ‘CERIFIED-MEASURE’ AS PROCESS_DESC, floor((MAX(EXEC_DATE)-MIN(EXEC_DATE))*24) || ' HOURS ' || mod(floor((MAX(EXEC_DATE)-MIN(EXEC_DATE))*24*60),60) || ' MINUTES ' || mod(floor((MAX(EXEC_DATE)-MIN(EXEC_DATE))*24*60*60),60) || ' SECS ' time_difference FROM spool_table LEFT JOIN HED_MEASURES ON SPOOL_TABLE.PROCESS_DESC=HED_MEASURES.MEASURE AND HED_MEASURES.NCQA_CERT=‘Y’ WHERE process_desc NOT IN (‘INITIALIZE’,’PRELIM’) AND to_date(EXEC_DATE, 'DD-MON-YYYY')= (SELECT to_date(MAX(EXEC_DATE), 'DD-MON-YYYY') FROM spool_table process_desc NOT IN (‘INITIALIZE’,’PRELIM’) )  ?add not in above query?

Comment: i need some serious help for this guys?